# Explicit use of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

Is there a way to explicitly use the MVT to prove this inequality: $\log(1+x)\leq \sqrt{x}$, or do we just find that the derivative of $h(x)=\sqrt{x}-\log(1+x)$ is greater than zero, hence the inequality is true.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a consequence of MVT that $h'\ge 0$ implies $h$ is non-strictly increasing

Comment: @user251257 Yes, I know that. But sometimes, in these type of exercises, we have that an explicit use of the MVT is possible... I was wondering if this is one of those.

Comment: you could just copy the proof, which is only an one-liner

Comment: @user251257 that's my backup plan lol

Comment: @An Old man in the sea: In my experience, MVT is often 'explicitly' used as a proof by contradiction for `these type of exercises'. For example, $x = 0$ is one root of $h(x) = 0$. One can show that there's at most one root for $h(x)$ since two or more roots would imply a point $c \neq 0$ where $h(c) = 0$ by Rolle's Thm (which is a special case of MVT).